# Shift+F10(run) and Shift+Option+F10(run..) shortcut doesn't work in WebStorm IDE

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

It has worked few days ago and since at some time it's not working.

Does anyone know what's reason and how to figure it out? 
I did restart my computer and it still doesn't work.

FYI, I'm using macbook pro touch-bar model.

Comment: Does WebStorm registers those shortcuts at all? Quite possible that your OS uses them for own needs (global keys). `WebStorm | Preferences | Keymap` -- there is `find by shortcut` button (next to search field) -- it allows you to press shortcut and see what actions are assigned to them. Does WebStorm even registers them (key pressed) .. or maybe you simply have no actions assigned to them?

Comment: Thanks for nice comment. I did the flow and found when I press **shift button**, WebStorm doesn't recognize it. It has happened unexpectedly at some time and do you know how to fix it..?

Comment: Pressing `Shift` alone will not register it -- it's just a modifier key. It has to be with combination with another key (e.g. `Shift+F10`). But in general -- no other ideas except checking your Mac OS Preferences (maybe you have activated some Accessibility option) -- sorry, not a Mac user myself.

Comment: That's alright. Thanks by the way. I tried `Shift+F10` and it only register `F10` .. So sad

Comment: Will other `Shift+` shortcuts work (got registered by IDE)? Or it is only `Shift+F10` that does not work? If that's the only one ... and you need that action to be accessible via shortcut -- try assigning another shortcut to it.

Comment: other `Shift+` shortcuts work well. It doesn't work only when it's `Shift+Fn`.. And as I said before it worked before, suddenly it's not working. I tried uninstall WebStorm and install again and still same. Maybe I should assign another key. Will you recommend nice key to replace Shift+F10(run)?

Comment: No "proper" ideas. Maybe you need to activate/disable some "Fn" or alike switch on your keyboard? No better ideas than that unfortunately. If you think it's an issue with WebStorm -- try backing up and deleting all settings -- this way you will start from scratch: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: I've found out what was wrong. I should have set Keymap to Mac OS X 10.5+. It was just Mac OS X. Then shortcut key to run automatically changed to `ctrl+r`. Thank you for trying to help me and I 'm really appreciated. Is there anyway I can give points to you? Cause this is my first time questioning in `stackoverflow.com` so I don't know how to take advantage of.